# Using fork() for split process- what's wrong with the program

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'd really love your help with understanding why doesn't the process reach the "son process" after using `fork()` command. I'm trying to write a program that runs another program, but It seems that the program dosen't even reach the son process. I can tell that since "son process" is not being printed to the screen, and I really wonder why.

Here's a sketch of the code- I can't even check if it is alright since as I said, it doesn't even reaching the son process, I always get "son exited with error".

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>



#define MAXARGV 5;

int main() {
    char* cmd;

    int child_status;

    char* s;
    char** argv;
    int counter;

    cmd= (char*) calloc( 5, sizeof(char)*20);
    s=(char*) calloc(1,sizeof(char)*20);
    argv=(char**) calloc(5, sizeof(char*)*20);




    printf("Please write a command\n");

    gets(cmd);

    counter = 0;

    while (strcmp(cmd, "exit") != 0) {

        int pid = fork();


        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("son process");

            while (sscanf(cmd, "%s", s) == 1) {

                strcpy(argv[counter], s);
                counter++;
            }

            execv(argv[0], argv);

            printf("the command is not legal");
            assert(0);

        }

        else {

            if (wait(&child_status) == -1) {
                printf("error waiting for pid=%d\n", pid);
                exit(-1);
            }

              if(WIFEXITED(child_status)!=0)
                    printf("son status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(child_status));
                else
                    printf("son exited with error\n");

        }

        printf("Please write a command");

        gets(cmd);

    }

    free(s);
    free(cmd);
    free(argv);
    printf("here as well");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Try `printf("son process\n");` with a newline.

Comment: Also add a call to `fflush(NULL);` just before the `fork()`

Comment: Also you may want to call it *child* process instead :)

Comment: You are "suffering from buffering".  Also, `execv` requires the full path name of the program, `execvp` might be easier.

Comment: @mux +1 for awesome gender-awareness skills! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The program reaches the `printf("son process")` just fine, but that just puts the string in a buffer inside the process and since you didn't `fflush()` it, it doesn't make it to the screen and is discarded with the rest of the process' memory in the `exec` call. Note, that `stdout` is normally line-buffered, so if you had newline there, it would auto-flush. Also `stderr` is by default unbuffered and more suitable for debug prints (`fprintf(stderr, "child process")`).
2. You are trying to assemble the command read from standard input in `argv`, but it only has memory for the actual arguments given to you, so you overrun this memory and get segmentation fault.
3. if `WIFEXITED` gives zero, you should use `WIFSIGNALED` and `WTERMSIG` to confirm that the error is indeed SIGSEGV.
4. `assert(0)` is not a good way to terminate process after error. `exit(1)` is. Assertions are only for conditions that indicate bug in the code itself if they happen and are often eliminated (by defining `NDEBUG`) from production code.